# PHP Output (json)

Tags: php, json, api

This is my script which is fetching a delivery report form my service providers api & displaying it in json format. I want this to be displayed in a table form using the mobile & status fields.

```
<?php

$uid="UID";
$pin="PIN";
$domain="DOMAIN";
$route="5";
$method="POST";
$rtype="json";
//---------------------------------

if(isset($_REQUEST['send']))
{

    $date=$_REQUEST['date'];

    $uid=urlencode($uid);
    $pin=urlencode($pin);
    $rtype=urlencode($rtype);
    $route=urlencode($route);
    $date=urlencode($date);
    $rtype=urlencode($rtype);

    $parameters="uid=$uid&pin=$pin&date=$date&route=$route&rtype=$rtype";

    $url="http://$domain/api/dlr.php";

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    if($method=="POST")
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$parameters);
    }
    else
    {
        $get_url=$url."?".$parameters;

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $get_url);
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER,0);  // DO NOT RETURN HTTP HEADERS 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);  // RETURN THE CONTENTS OF THE CALL
    $return_val = curl_exec($ch);


    if($return_val=="")
    echo "Process Failed, Please check your connecting domain, username or password.";
    else

    echo "$return_val";


}

echo "<form name='f1' method='post'>";

echo "<p> Date (##-##-####): <input name='date' > </p>";

echo "<p> <input type='submit' value='Send' name='send'></p>";

echo "</form";

?>
```

**OUTPUT**

[{"smsid":"211677113","mobile":"9876546577","status":"Delivered"},{"smsid":"211677166","mobile":"98765454377","status":"Delivered"}]

Comment: Don't see a question here.

Comment: Where's the problem? ``json_decode`` and accessing the object like ``$obj = json_decode($return_val);``

Comment: Hey, The problem is i am getting the output in json, which is echoed by $return_val. Now what i want is it is displayed in tabel format instead using just the mobile & status fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `json_decode()`

```
$str = json_decode('[{"smsid":"211677113","mobile":"9876546577","status":"Delivered"},{"smsid":"211677166","mobile":"98765454377","status":"Delivered"}]', true);
print_r($str);
```

it will convert your json string in an array then loop through your array and print output as you wish like

```
foreach($str as $k=>$v) {
  echo $v['smsid'];
  echo $v['mobile'];
  echo $v['status'];
}
```

Comment: Hey Rakesh, The method works & i get my output as array can you help me loop through it. I am not versed with coding so a little help will be appreciated.

Comment: Here is the array : Array ( [0] => Array ( [smsid] => 211953832 [mobile] => 9435109455 [status] => Delivered ) [1] => Array ( [smsid] => 211953998 [mobile] => 9435049323 [status] => Delivered ) [2] => Array ( [smsid] => 211979594 [mobile] => 9678070770 [status] => Delivered ) )

Answer (score 0):

Try to show table

```
<?php
    $a = json_decode('[{"smsid":"211677113","mobile":"9876546577","status":"Delivered"},{"smsid":"211677166","mobile":"98765454377","status":"Delivered"}]');
?>
<table border="1">
<?php
    foreach($a as $k=>$v){?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$v->mobile?></td>
            <td><?=$v->status?></td>
        </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response, in my above question the string you have used to decode is echoed by $return_val. What i want is instead of echoing the string it is displayed as a table. What you are doing is using a static data to decode but i need it to be dynamic, i have tried your script & it is working to decode the data into a table as a separate php script but i wasn't able to integrate it into the existing script.

Comment: $a = json_decode($return_val); and then display it to html table